# Reading varbinary value from WikiMedia database in Java

Tags: mysql, wikipedia, wikimedia

I'm trying to get the result of a MySQL query (WikiMedia; a "**varbinary field**") using the following code:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT *  FROM `redirect` WHERE `rd_namespace` = 0 AND `rd_title` = XY);

        while (rs.next()) {         
             title = rs.getString("title");
        }
```

Unfortunately "title" kills all the german "umlauts" (ä, ü, ö etc)

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem :-)

[image]